# Alter form in form_alter with method

Tags: 8

I have a form that I want to override title of textfield. I managed to do that with this snippet in _form_alter function

```
$form['some_wrapper']['email'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Change this title'),
];
```

Wondering if i could just override this with some method like setValue?

Comment: Do you mean `$form['some_wrapper']['email']['#title'] = t('Change this title');`?

Comment: Well I guess it can be done like that also, but I was wondering if this can/needs to be done with some method or is it made like old school D7 way.

Comment: Render arrays are still just arrays, they haven't been classed in D8 (too complicated; though I wouldn't bet against someone trying to get it classed for D9/10)